# Drupal content update to Facebook page

Tags: social-network

When I publish content – for instace an article – on a Drupal site, I'd like Drupal to push a status update with a link to the article to a Facebook company page.

I know there are a lot of Drupal modules that offer Facebook integration, but does any of them offer this particular functionality? Or is perhaps the best way to go to generate an RSS feed and use a third-part app like http://twitterfeed.com/ to push it to Facebook?

The site in question is a Drupal 6 site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Drupal for Facebook](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb) module gives you integration on a number of levels, including (with some extra work) automatic push to a Facebook page you have access to.

However, you might get better results by letting visitors to your website post references to their own timeline using something like [ShareThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharethis). This will use your audience as multipliers of your message, not just on Facebook but on other social media sites as well.